# Dynamic Body size in angular2

Tags: angular

Here is the code we are giving dynamic body size in angularjs.

```
  $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event) {
                var biggestHeight = 0;
                var height = 0;
                $(".screen").find('*').each(function(){
                    height = $(this).position().top + $(this).height() + 100;
                    if (height > biggestHeight ) {
                        biggestHeight = height;
                    }
                });
                $(".screen").height(biggestHeight);
            });
```

How to use this in angular2?

This is simple screen code

```
<div class="screen">
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
 <button type="submit" class="generated-button" (click)="NotImplemented" style="position: absolute;width: 67px;height: 35px;left: 356px;top: 311px;">Button</button>
 </form>
 </div>
```

This is simple html code ,Here we have many input . we want to get the heighest position in list of input and set the height to screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re-implement this feature in angular2 you can use element property binding support https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#attribute-binding

You can calculate your height and set directly:

```
<app-some-element [height]="height"></app-some-element>
```

or

```
<div class="screen" #screen>
 ...
</div>
```

Where `height` can be calculated inside component

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.height = ...;
}
```

If you need to set this height to some child element - you always can use `@ViewChild()` directive to get element reference

```
@ViewChild('screen')
screen
```

So your code would be

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  var childs = this.screen.nativeElement.children; 
  //or querySelectorAll('*') to get all elements in tree

  for(var i=0; i<childs.length; i++) {
     //calculate child biggest height
  }

  this.screen.nativeElement.height = ...;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have added some code .Please check and make me understandable

Comment: You can add ref variable to your `screen` component: `<div class="screen" #screen>` and get it reference in your component `@ViewChild('screen') screen`. Having this you can access direct DOM property from `this.screen.nativeElement`. I've updated my code

Comment: Ok .. I want to get the highest height from list of input inside the screen selector .and Then I want to assign height to screen content .

Comment: Not a problem. You have `this.screen.nativeElement` as DOM element reference, so you can use `this.screen.nativeElement.children` or `this.screen.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('*')` to access all childs. I have added example

Comment: Thanks a lot....U saved  me a many days ....and also how to get the highest top from list of selector

Comment: Comparing next component height with previous I think: `let height = 0; for(...)  { height = height > childs[i].height ? height : childs[i].height; }`

Comment: height is not applying in ui side

Comment: Plz try to use `.clientHeight` instead. Height is not DOMElement property. Or `.style.height`